# Columns not connected? Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to add margins between the columns? Right now it looks like this: http://prntscr.com/5fcdht

It's just the simple column setup:

```
<div class="container" id="page_content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <p class="lead">paragraph</p>
            <p>paragraph</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p class="lead">paragraph</p>
            <p>paragraph</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean margins?

Comment: There is a gutter there, it's made with padding. What is the intention? You can have an inner div with a background color or you can put borders on the columns with css. You can't put a "margin" because the grid will not work

Comment: As @Christina was getting at, I'd just increase the horizontal padding if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Not so much margin, but rather giving more space between both divs, that cuts into the size of the left.

```
<div class="container" id="page_content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <p class="lead">paragraph</p>
            <p>paragraph</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
            <p class="lead">paragraph</p>
            <p>paragraph</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```